# Getting post id on send_headers action in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible in WordPress to get ID of current post in send_headers hook? global $post and $wp_query doesn't work or i did something wrong.

```
class myClass {

public function __construct() {

    add_action('send_headers', array($this, 'myFunction'));

}

public function myFunction() {

    // need to get post ID here

}
```

Comment: I have been trying to get the post ID via `$post` and `$wp_query` within the `send_headers` action, but this is also failing for me too.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like WordPress hasn't gotten to the point of initiating `$wp_query` when the action `send_headers` is triggered.

As the question asks how to get the post ID this answer assumes that you have the slug in the url instead. If the slug is the last part of the url then this will get the post ID for you.

```
$post = get_posts ( array (
    'name' => pathinfo ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] )['filename']
) )[0];
echo $post->ID;
```

This result will need to be tested per use, but should work for most purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You even can try something like this:

```
global $wp;
$post =  get_page_by_path($wp->request);
echo $post->ID;
```